# Windows console application voice would not change

Tags: c#, voice

Here is the code I am writing to change from the female synth voice to a male but it will not change it continues to run the female voice. Any idea why that might be?

```
//Opening dialog to the user
Console.WriteLine("Console cpu burn by mixedBreed" + "\nPlease wait while I look over your system");
Console.WriteLine();
string author = "Console cpu burn by mixed Breed" + " Please wait while I look over your system";
synth.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male);
synth.Speak(author);
```

Comment: Do you have a male voice pack installed?

Comment: hmm I don't know I assumed I did honestly since I can see it in the list of three voices and at school it worked just fine but maybe someone already installed the voices. I'll figure how to check and see about getting it installed

Comment: Hmm I can't get that method to work either, but I can get it to choose a mail voice, I will add it as an answer. What OS are you using at home vs at school?

Comment: if you're on windows 7, go to control panel -> speech recognition -> text to speech. you'll be able to check the installed voices.

Comment: yes it is windows 7 home on both machines but doing what you said I only have Microsoft Anna installed. So, there is my real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I can also not get the `SelectVoiceByHints` method to work, the voice never changes. If you want to switch to a male voice though, here is some code that will work:

```
using (var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    var voices = synth.GetInstalledVoices().Dump();
    var male = voices.FirstOrDefault(v => v.VoiceInfo.Gender == VoiceGender.Male);
    if (male != null)
    {
        synth.SelectVoice(male.VoiceInfo.Name);
    }

    synth.Speak("Hello");
}
```